# Change series point colour on hover

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I am trying to get the points on my graph in a particular series to change colour when the any point in the series is hovered over. i.e. hovering over a point in series 1 makes all points in series 1 change colour (and are hence highlighted).

This is made a little more difficult as I initially colour the points based on their value.

I tried to adapt the answer from [highcharter change highlight color on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066731/highcharter-change-highlight-color-on-hover), but it doesnt seem to be working with points that have been coloured in as they **do not** change on hover.

```
library(highcharter)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

# generate data
data = data.table(
  CJ(x = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-01-10"), by = "day"),
     group = seq(1,2))
)
data[, value := round(runif(n=20, -5,5),4)]

# color points based on value
data = data.table(data %>% mutate(cat=cut(value, breaks=quantile(data[value!=0]$value, seq(0,1,0.1)), labels=seq(1,10))))
colf = colorRampPalette(colors = c("red","yellow", "green"))
cols = colf(10)
data[, color := as.factor(cols[cat])]

# get point position
data$x = datetime_to_timestamp(data$x)
data = data.table(data %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(y = order(order(value))-sum(value<0,na.rm=T)))

# plot data
highchart() %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime", dateTimeLabelFormats = list(day = '%d of %b')) %>%
  hc_add_series(data[group==1], name = "group 1", marker = list(symbol = fa_icon("circle"))) %>%
  hc_add_series(data[group==2], name = "group 2", marker = list(symbol = fa_icon("circle"))) %>%
  hc_chart(type = "scatter") %>%
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "Performance = <b>{point.value}</b> <br> Group = <b>{point.name}</b>") %>%
  # hover over part
  hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(
      stickyTracking = FALSE,
      events = list(
        mouseOver = JS("function() { if(this.options.color !== 'red') {this.update({color: 'red'})} }"),
        mouseOut = JS("function() { if(this.options.color === 'red') {this.update({color: '#ddd'})} }")
      ),
      states = list(
        hover = list(
          enabled = TRUE,
          lineWidth = 10
        )
      )
    ))
```

The graph:

[image]

Comment: Hi. What do you think about the new Inactive State in Highcharts? I am not sure if it is available in Highcharter now, but the author could share a development branch for you so you could pull the newest Highcharts with Inactive State. Here you have an example of it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2wu3jrmt/

Let me know if it is enough for you. If you want to try a different approach (from your question) let me know and I will check it.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am looking for!! It doesnt seem to be enables in `highcharter` by default, is it available yet? Thanks

Comment: its available in the development version (https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter)

Comment: Great, I'll put it in answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Inactive State: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.states.inactive

It's been included in Highcharts since 7.1.0 and enabled by default so all you need to do is to make sure that you are using the newest Highcharter.

Here you have an example of it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2wu3jrmt

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'scatter'
  },

  series: [{
    data: [4, 3, 5, 6, 2, 5]
  }, {
    data: [2, 5, 3, 7, 3, 1]
  }, {
    data: [1, 1, 6, 3, 4, 3]
  }]

});
```

Comment: is there a way to change the color of the points as in my example? i.e. so they would all go black on hover and then return to their original colors? Many thanks